# will-change css usage on transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, will-change

i am trying to use `will-change` to make an animation perform better. I have a page-container that would animate `left` and `padding-right` in order to move and reveal side menu.

```
.page-container {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1001;
    will-change: left, padding-right;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-out, padding-right 0.4s ease-out;
    }
```

When button is clicked to move container/show menu, a class is added to container parent and css is changed to:

```
.page-wrapper.menu-opened .page-container {
            left: 240px;
            padding-right: 240px;
            }
```

`will-change` doesn't seem to have any impact. Am i using it right, or how it should be used?

Comment: can you share a demo for us to see what is causing the animation to not perform "better".

Answer (score 0):

Use  `transform: translateX(240px)` instead of `left: 240px`. The reason this doesn't perform well is that the `position` property doesn't support hardware acceleration, while the `transform` property does.

[Here is an example of translateX in action](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/QjBwpB) for a menu opening/closing.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i think you are wrong. This shows that position properties can be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/will-change I have tried using transform but the problem is that when i use transform, padding-right transition is not fluid as i want to add right padding to container so that content stays in page and doesn't leave page

Comment: They can be used, any animateable property can be used, that doesn't mean that the browser can properly prepare for or hardware accelerate them. Padding-right is another property that can't be hardware accelerated. Check out https://csstriggers.com/ and Behold The Consequences Of Your Actions. Any property here that can be done on the compositor alone opens the potential for hardware acceleration.